# extract analysis and synthesis weighting filters

Tags: filter-bank

For regular FIR filters we can feed an impulse signal to get the coefficients, but how about filterbanks?

Let's say I have a uniformly modulated filterbank with hop size H and FFT size M, implemented as weighted overlap-add method [1]. Is there a way to construct an input signal to extract the analysis and synthesis weights?

1. R. Crochiere and L. R. Rabiner, Multirate Digital Signal Processing,
   Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice-Hall, 1983.

Comment: well if you have a filterbank, you simply get a bank of impulse responses when feeding in an impulse. Not quite sure where the confusion arises from?

Comment: or is this about a *polyphase* filter bank, specifically, and you want to piece together the original prototype impulse response?

Comment: Unless you have access to the individual filter bank outputs, that might be hard to do... especially if the filter bank is perfect reconstruction.

Comment: @MarcusMüller , yes I’d like to know if it’s possible to put the pieces together and get the original prototype impulse response

Comment: are you doing analysis **and** resynthesis?  or just analysis?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I can do both.

Comment: Well, when you're doing phase-coherent synthesis, [there is a notion of *complementary windows*, which are windows where the trailing slope of a window adds to the rising slope of the following window and adds to 1.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56400/hanning-and-hamming-window/56408#56408)  For non-coherent synthesis, you want a constant-power window where the squares of the windows add to 1.  But for analysis only, you need not worry about complementarity at all.